# The function exchanged call in php codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I have the following Function :

```
public function add(){
    $this->load->view('backend/video/add');
}

public function addvideo(){

        $nama = $this->input->post('title');
        $url  = $this->input->post('url');
        $data = array('nama' => $title,
                    'url' => $url);
        if ($this->MTestimoni->add($data,$where = 'video')) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('notif','Video berhasil ditambahkan');
            redirect(base_url('admin/video'));
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('gagal','Video gagal ditambahkan');
            redirect(base_url('admin/video'));
        }

}
```

but when i call **add()** the function run function of **addvideo()** and vice versa, i dont now why the function exchanger run function

Comment: can we see your routes.php

Comment: comment your redirect() method in your code and check your if condition work properly or not.
make sure that no changes in your route.php config file

Answer (score 0):

you functions are fine, but whenever you use your route to call the add method, the view is loaded. 
Now I think You are using form to submit the data and you must use the submit route as 
base_url().'controller/addVideo'
and then try to check with your method..

I hope it will help.